# Getting server error 503 from server after multiple refreshes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have setup a subdomain via wildcard in my asp.net application. The subdomain routing works perfect, but for some reason if I refresh the page two times quickly I keep getting this error:

```
The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
```

Stacktrace:

```
[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.]
   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request) +365
   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address) +111
   WebApplication3.Controllers.OtherController.Dynamic(String someValue, String Id) +2168
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +191
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +229
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +77
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +69
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +387
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +188
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +602
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +195
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +128
```

The subdomain route is setup like this:

```
   routes.MapSubDomainRoute("OtherRoute",
                                     "{someValue}", // SubDomain 
                                     "{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                                      new { controller = "Other", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
                                      new { someValue = new SubDomainConstraint() } // constraint so we only deal the subdomains we want
                                      );
```

what could be the reason behind this issue ? Can someone help me out?

And the subdomain that I'm trying to access is:

```
http://subdomain.example.com/routeIdParameter
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] so we can see the controller action being executed.

Answer (score 1):

api cannot reach the installed servera

Comment: What do you mean by that ? I can reach it normally if I don't refresh too many times....